# Would wearing clothes over fur be uncomfortable?

Tags: clothing, hair

Wearing headwear over hair isn't very pleasant when hair is relatively short. Does this hold for fur?

In case of humanoid creatures covered with short (up to 5mm) fur, like cats or dogs have, would wearing clothing be uncomfortable?
How about longer?
10? 15? 20?

I'm not very hairy so I can't really say, but experiences of very hairy people would be very welcome.

Edit:

Very good point.

Race is humanoid and bipedal with five fingered hands.
Pregnancy is about 9 months with a similarly long bringup time as with humans.

Technology levels:

Since the society had to evolve, I'm thinking ancient, medieval and modern.

Purpose:

Versatility. The race would retain the human sweat gland capacity by making the fur "bristle" so in hot environment it would both protect from sun and it would reduce the need for clothes during cold nights.

But their fur coats aren't perfect for all locations and a black longer fur would be terrible in the hot areas. To solve that I thought about wearing white headwear/robes to insulate against heat.

For colder areas I thought additional clothing layers would be perfect, even if usually thinner than what we need to use.

Another purpose:

Culture.

Ancient times had a religion that introduced a goddess similar to Gaia that also introduced decency (cover up your sexual organs) as a part of a written "how to be good" book.
It's worth noting that most of the societies did it anyway.

Medieval times had translated that to a cultural heritage in response to pre-medieval debauchery that was pointed out by scholars of the time as a cause for societal collapse.

In modern times they cover certain areas of their bodies due to mating rituals being better for the offspring if mating isn't random which was often the case before decency laws were passed in medieval times. Thus a pair bonding culture developed in the species with sexual organs and mammalian glands being covered for "decency".

Beaches allow for less clothing of course.

Although fur would be a natural cover, its relative shortness means it doesn't really cover much.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what kind of clothing? What is the purpose of it? Fur is one of the reasons why most animals don't need clothing. Could you also establish how advanced you want the clothes to be? Stone age furs or synthetic fabrics?

Comment: Please define 'uncomfortable' more clearly. Individual tolerances to itchiness (for example) can vary significantly between different individuals within the same village. Also 'uncomfortable' could also mean encumberance or constriction of physical movement, which would be an issue for people expecting to have to do physical labour/combat

Comment: That is kind of what i'm asking - whether theres a noticeable difference in comfort levels or would you mostly be able to ignore it. Men doing physical work often take off their tops which i assume would be the case here also unless protection is needed.

Comment: Lots of people have fur on their heads and in other places, and wear hats or corresponding clothing articles over said fur. The vast majority of them don't find it uncomfortable at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to answer questions is to look for examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Dogs have fur, but don't find clothing particularly uncomfortable. Our dog even brings us her jumper and asks us to put it on when she gets cold!

Comment: Good point! Was it difficult to make them accept clothing?

Comment: Nope, our dog loves hers. (She's a small dog and England isn't known for being warm which may contribute!)

Comment: Cool! Is there a difference in clothing acceptance between long and short furs?

Comment: @GensysLTD Not that I've seen. Our dog actually has short hair when groomed then it grows out long and I've only seen her ask for it when short haired but that's probably just because it's colder. She doesn't object to having a coat put on when her hair is long.

Comment: Hm. It would suggest that having short hair doesnt make the clothes uncomfortable of which i was worried. And dog being cold is a discomfort which seems to be removed by clothing. Very good. Thanks.

Comment: A tangent: some people would want to shave/otherwise remove parts or whole of their fur as a fashion statement. Do you have to worry about ingrown hairs etc... when shaving off fur?

Comment: @GensysLTD No idea, we don't shave her. Common sense would suggest probably yes though :) If you want to ask that feel free to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @GensysLTD Dogs aren't shaved with a razor, electric clippers are used, so ingrowing hair is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that a society of people who are naturally covered in fur would invent articles of clothing that would be comfortable to wear for them. I'm not taking into account individual tolerances or preferences, I'm talking about the general idea.

The articles of clothing that we, as humans, use, are made to be comfortable for us based on our physiology. Every article of clothing, from the skimpiest swimwear to the most bulky NBC suit or space suit, is made with the basic principle that it will fit our bodies and can be worn without creating discomfort or pain.

As a civilization, we made extensive testing through the ages with many kind of materials, invented some more, especially through the last century, perfected them and also worked on size, cut, etc, in order to be able to fit and clothe everyone on the planet with comfortable clothes, and we succeeded.

The fact that some people, plus-size people for example, find it very difficult to find good and comfortable clothing due to being out of the 'standard shape', as defined by the clothing industry, is mostly a monetary issue coupled with a societal issue; the clothing industry thinks there's little benefit to be made by making plus-sized clothing and society carries an image of the 'perfect body' that punishes those people because they are so far from the unrealistic perfection shown in ads and magazines, not due to a lack of knowledge or technology to produce them.

Comment: Actually a lot of clothing (ties, corsets, etc) is profoundly uncomfortable. They act as status symbols though.

Comment: Yes, I imagine they would but that doesn't answer the "is wearing cloth over fur uncomfortable in and of itself".
So while I agree that articles would look and feel different, the issue remains if fur and clothing are incompatible.